# How to semplify this database schema and query?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

This is my database schema:

```
Post:
-id
-title
-body
-date

User:
-id
-name
-password

Category:
-id
-title

Post_Category:
-id
-id_post
-id_category

Post_User:
-id
-id_user
-id_post

Post_Like:
-id
-id_user
-id_post

Comment:
-id
-id_user
-id_post
-body
```

"Like" in my project works like "facebook likes".

In homepage I need to get latest 50 post with informations about categories, users, likes, comments.

Is there a way to avoid this complex query that join these 7 tables ?

Comment: I don't think that the query is too complex. If you have really heavy load and the requested data is repeating a lot you could try using small objects with sophisticated caches instead of the query, but those 7 joins are all over the id - so no problem if the indices are set correctly.

Comment: Try **not** using the surrogate keys in junction tables (unless you have [specific reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info) for them). This should help with the write performance, and probably a little bit with the read performance due to the better cache utilization.